# Can I use this board to control multiple vibration motors?

Tags: motor

I am looking at this: https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver

Although it’s meant for servos, I was wondering if I could use them to control vibration motors.

Motors like these: Diameter Flat Button Type 3V-4.5V Cellphone Micro Vibration Motor (Pack of 3) https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07CQXZBZD/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_tai_yzSvDb8V7JAF4

Any suggestions? I would like to control about 200 motors with minimal number of controllers.

Each motor should be controllable individually.

Comment: It's not really meant for servos, it's LED driver chip that can be used to drive position of servo too (with on board pull up resistors). It could be strong enough to drive low current vibration motors, but there must be snubber circuit.

Comment: And if you need on/off only, there are led drivers for that too.

Comment: @kiiv From what I have seen the board can drive 25mA max - but those motors appear to be 66mA from what I have managed to find.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no.  Those boards are designed to generate a low power PWM signal for passing to a servo with a built-in controller. To use that output directly with a motor you will need to add a transistor to each output to control the motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbbfWT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: instead of a diode, I'd recommend a capacitor across the motor, I think that would allow finer control for a square signal, and reduces power factor for a high-frequency signal

Comment: @tuskiomi Good point. Had my head in relay mode ;)

Comment: @SimSon In the question there is this final note: `Each motor should be controllable individually.`

Comment: How to you control each motor individually?

Comment: Also can you run all or some of the motors at the same time? Like how you light up only some Leds in a board to spell out a message.

Comment: You have to build this circuit for every single motor. Then connect each of the MOSFET gates to a single PWM output of the used PWM boards. If you only need on off control, you should use shift registers with the circuit above.